# Sed error message

Tags: bash, sed

I use command date

```
PARAM=`date "+%a %d %B %Y"`
echo "$PARAM"
```

and I get

```
Sat 24 June 2017
```

Then I want to change the word new for $PARAM

```
sed -i 's/new/'$PARAM'/g' letter'.php'
```

But I get the following message error

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 9: unterminated `s' command
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: Why are you testing with `-i`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of bash word splitting after parameter expansion of `PARAM`. So double quoting it to make the command part as a whole:

```
sed -i 's/new/'"$PARAM"'/g' letter'.php'
```